# How to create a bitcoin transaction without inputs

Tags: transactions, coinbase-transaction, transaction-input

How can I create a transaction without inputs and it will be broadcasted but of course won't get confirmed? I would like the simplest method to do this

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Only the coinbase transaction is allowed to have a null, or non-existent input, and the only way to create that is to mine a block. Moreover, it must adhere to additional rules, such as the inclusion of the block height in the coinbase section of the vin (the scriptSig) as per BIP 34.

Unless you happen to run a mining pool, or have enough hashpower to solo mine a block, you cannot do this.

Creating a transaction with no inputs whatsoever is not possible without a hard fork.

Comment: But I've seen video evidences of this happening. A transaction was made but its never confirmed cos it's not real.

Comment: Do you have a link to the video? That sounds extremely unlikely, and more likely as a way to sell you on some scam service

Comment: https://youtu.be/s8Ij1oPYBsU that's a video evidence. It's very real.

Comment: @sissy That is a scam, those videos are aiming to sell you software which will steal any crypto on you computer after you install it. The videos are a way to market them to people who are not familiar with the space and are looking for shortcuts/hacks

Comment: Coinbase transactions have inputs. They just reference null outpoints.

Comment: @pinhead Right, my mistake. I've update the answer

Comment: In addition, BIP144 uses a 0 to mark SegWit serialization. That 0 would be interpreted as "tx has no inputs" by non-SegWit nodes and rejected: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0144.mediawiki#Serialization